# Listen Broadcast Before application uninstall

Tags: android

I have installed Avg Antivirus for testing purpose.
After Testing when I have tried to uninstall that Antivirus,Antivirus has prompted me that 'are you sure you want to remove this application?'.
That prompt screen is generated by antivirus application. After that screen I got System prompt with OK and CANCEL Button. so, That prompt was put by antivirus application.

Now my question is...

How can I put prompt screen for user in my application as same as explain above?
I know about "**android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED**" but it received after application has been fully uninstall.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've added the following intent-filter and now I receive the dialog to chose activity. I think you should play with this filter to display your activity (especially with data part of the filter).

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".UninstallIntentActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="package"  />
        </intent-filter>



    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: it works fine , but i don't want during uninstall for all activity. I want for specific activity uninstall time. And I do not want to receive dialog for install packager and my application option.

Comment: Without modifying the sources I think that it is impossible to implement

Comment: Use `<data android:scheme="package" android:pathPattern="com.my.app" />` to filter specific package delete intent

Comment: @Yury can I start a `Receiver` instead of starting an `Activity`?

Comment: I do not see any obstacles to do this, however I did not try. You may try and then report if it is working.