# How to clear db when app is uninstalled in android

Tags: android, database, android-intent, sms

Im using database to store messages, and if i uninstall my app and again reinstall the same app, the db remains same, but i want to clear my database, how to solve this?

Comment: Normally everything should be deleted when you uninstall you app. How did you test it? Did you really uninstall the app manually? Where does you app store the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To listen the uninstall event you have to implement a broadcast received, like:

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name=".UninstallIntentActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="package"  />
    </intent-filter>



</activity>

</application>
```

And then in your UninstallIntentActivity you have to use the next line to delete your database:

```
context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

You can see more about this topic here [Listen Broadcast Before application uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633761/listen-broadcast-before-application-uninstall)

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

All data including databases,preference,local data files stored in internal storage are deleted on an uninstall.They will only stay intact on application update.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not ordinary situation, cause when you uninstall app - all db are removed automaticaly. But if it doesn't happen - try to clear data in Menu - Manage App - your app - Clear data before uninstalling.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just forgot to add below line in onUpgrade method of DatabaseHelper class

```
onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
```

Answer (score -1):

below code can help you to delete your database from your application

```
/**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
        db.close();
    }
```

make one method in class where you handle your database handling means. where you crate other methods like add,update etc..

Comment: how to call this method, before Uninstalling of the app?