# How can i remove DB record from server at the time of app uninstall

Tags: android, multithreading, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to track my app pkg , whenever user uninstall it, then i want to remove user record from the server side, to achieve this goal, I'm trying to make a **worker thread** to send post request in server using these ans. i know these kind of question are asked multiple time and i have also tried it, but i don't find any solution yet.
any kind of help like external link will be appreciated

1. [Listen Broadcast Before application uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633761/listen-broadcast-before-application-uninstall)
2. [How to clear db when app is uninstalled in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118427/how-to-clear-db-when-app-is-uninstalled-in-android)

   ```
   Thread PostZReqThread = new Thread() {
           private Handler handler = new Handler();


                   handler.post(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                           // my Post request ..
                       }
                   });
   ```

Comment: It seems that both the links you have provided are exactly what you are looking for _and_ have accepted answers. So if you have faced issues implementing those solutions, post those code snippets or the errors thrown

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listen Broadcast Before application uninstall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633761/listen-broadcast-before-application-uninstall)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633761/listen-broadcast-before-application-uninstall) from the comment and one more stack example, I figured out the answer using broadcast receiver and a simple thread. 
The essential  Part  of code are following -
     menifeast recevier code

```
 <receiver android:name="install_notifier">
 <intent-filter android:priority="100">
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
 <data android:scheme="package" />
 </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

// class to receive  broadcast

```
 public class Unintsall_notifier extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("TAG","GET_INTENT_HIT...");
    }
 }
```