# Android : Perform action when user presses Clear Data in Manage Apps

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

Just as we can handle uninstallation of an app: [Listen Broadcast Before application uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633761/listen-broadcast-before-application-uninstall) , is there any way or any intent available, through which i can handle CLEAR DATA?

I want to perform some steps when user presses "Clear Data" in "Manage apps" screen.