# Is it possible to intercept app uninstall?

Tags: android, android-intent, uninstallation

Is it possible to intercept app uninstall and make some job? E.g. my app modifies some files of device, so it would be neat before uninstalling just rollback changes made by my app.

Any hints, ideas?

Comment: Or to display a toast saying `"I'm scared! I want to live!!!"`

Comment: there is a broadcast. not sure if it is send before or after app deletion

Comment: @njzk2 : The broadcast will be sent only after uninstall.

Comment: @barmaley haha, indeed. But it can get quite creepy http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0KTUysrwgQ

Comment: @barmaley : There are apps which needs password to uninstall. Try that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the similar issue

[Listen Broadcast Before application uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633761/listen-broadcast-before-application-uninstall)

Then as said you have to use the intent-filter for delete as given in the above link.

```
<activity
    android:name=".UninstallIntentActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="package"  />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and when you get notified , do whatever you want.

Comment: This will intercept all `DELETE` requests, not just the one for your app, forcing your app into a chooser for all uninstalls.

Comment: Hmmm... in this case how should I differentiate between all delete requests?

Comment: `<data android:scheme="package" android:pathPattern="com.my.app" />` makes differentiation magic :)

Comment: I'm sorry: `android:pathPattern` as well as `android:path` doesn't help!