# How to detect if my app was uninstalled?

Tags: android

I understand that this question has been asked a number of times. But I would like to know if I can open a webpage after my app is uninstalled.

Before you say no, Please note that there are some apps like apus launcher which can detect when their app is uninstalled and can open a webpage after uninstall.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Unless you have a service running the background, meaning that the app is always active, there wouldn't be a way to detect it.  So I would assume that a background service would be what you're looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18658255/1225413 see here

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Apus Launcher's uninstall bahavior, but this provides a pretty definitive no to your question...

'The package that is being installed does not receive this Intent.'

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED

Answer (score 0):

Just installed Apus Launcher, ran it, and then uninstalled it.  As I expected, it doesn't put up any webpage after uninstall - I fear you have been misinformed.

(Apus is however doing some clever things, such as placing an overlay around the chooser dialog to encourage you to choose Apus if your system has multiple apps capable of handling a particular intent).

I notice that there are multiple Apus produced apps - if you have multiple of these installed, then it's very possible to write two apps that each detect the other app being uninstalled - but not the case that any one of the apps can detect its own uninstallation.

Comment: I downloaded the app from this link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apusapps.launcher
and it works. I got redirected to a web page after I uninstall the app. It asked for my feedback on why I uninstalled.

Comment: Yes, that's the one I installed, and later uninstalled.  I think the most likely answer is that you have some other app installed that notices the uninstall and takes you to some relevant webpage.