# Can I permanently change a variable in an Android app even if they reinstall?

Tags: android, eclipse, image, google-play, sharedpreferences

I have an Android application I am working on in which the client wants a promotional page in which the first 100 people who download the app get a 10% discount on their order. From what I researched I understand that Google Play doesn't have a very user-friendly way to do this, but for my work-around I wanted to have a "not used coupon" and a "used coupon" image that the waitress could see and type in a short verification code to permanently change the coupon on the app to "used."

From what I read I can use the SharedPreferences to make this happen, but what if the person uninstalls the application and then reinstalls it to get a fresh coupon? Is there anyway in Android to prevent this from happening?

Comment: First Idea - save your preferences to cloud server or make remote DB for users. For key - use Device ID. Device ID - is a unique idetificator. For the sample. `User install your app -> connecting to cloud\server-> post id of device ->ok`. After that. `User reinstall and install app again`. So you `connect to cloud\server again` and `check for existing id of device`. **If in DB contains this id - try to get discount will be reject.**

Comment: @deathember Thanks for your reply. To clarify, I could run a cloud server that ran the user's unique Android_ID and if that has not yet been put in to my database, they are able to use the coupon and then the method adds their ID to my database. This way the server always checks for duplicate ID's before allowing the user to use the coupon.

Comment: May be that help for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633761/listen-broadcast-before-application-uninstall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a very simple API for backing up and a [specific helper for SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/SharedPreferencesBackupHelper.html). You don't need to have your own server for this.

http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/backupapi.html

footnote:
Never use device ID. Use the account ID to identify the user and the ANDROID_ID to identify the device. If you use IMEI, MAC, serial number or anything that stays the same when device ownership changes, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: It should be noted that Backup and Restore is a feature that can be turned off by the user.  I believe that there is a prompt for the user to set this when the device is initialized, and the user can choose not to use it then, or at any future time by unchecking it in Settings.  So the discount might be applied multiple times by a savvy user.  But with all such schemes, you have to consider how likely it is that a user will bother to uninstall and reinstall in the first place.  I mean, this is not access to Ft. Knox that we are talking about; you have to accept a certain amount of leakage.

Comment: Thanks for directing me to that API, I think that will be the best way to implement this discount. @Carl As far as the user "hacking" the code to re use it multiple times, I agree that it probably would not become an issue...but is there any possible Java logic I could place in the onClick listener that made sure that this setting was enabled? My main objective is to let the client know any way the coupon could be replicated so that could not come back on me.