# Tracking uninstall of android app

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to track uninstalls of my android app . How many users are uninstalling app . So whenever user uninstall app I want to call api.
Is it possible? what are the possible ways to track uninstalls?

Comment: No. You can track other app uninstall but not self. But you have an alternative, If you are using GCM in your app, call your GCM server with RegId and the GCM server will return you if the app is actually uninstalled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can maintain a table of users actively using your app.After that call a Webservice at a fixed point in your code that will show if it is active or not. If the app is not used for a certain time which you can call expiretime, then you can call it as inactive.

Otherwise you can Use GCM.
From GCM documentation: "An application can be automatically unregistered after it is uninstalled from the device. However, this process does not happens right away, as Android does not provide an uninstall callback."

Actaully, the device will tell GCM the application was uninstalled when GCM tries to send the next push notifiaction.

Such as,While notifying friends, GCM will send a `NotRegistered` error to your notification server when this failure occurs but it won't be immediate.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty more ways of tracking uninstalls.
You can run a ping service from the device to the server periodically. You can also send blank notifications intermittently to make sure the app is still on the device. You can ignore rendering these notifications to your users.

If you were looking for a pure technical explanation of how GCM and Apple track uninstalls then you can read about it here. 
Track App Uninstalls effectively (https://blog.clevertap.com/track-app-uninstalls-effectively/) I have also covered alternative methods if you wanted to implement the uninstall tracking yourself!

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can track other app uninstall but not self. But you have an alternative, If you are using GCM in your app, call your GCM server with RegId and the GCM server will return you if the app is actually uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [uninstall.io](http://uninstall.io/). This might be useful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

as Ravi mentioned you can never know uninstall for your app but you can use the trick. Check out below link

[Listen Broadcast Before application uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633761/listen-broadcast-before-application-uninstall)

If this helps you do not forget to mark this as answer or if any query you can ask me.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

To track users who have uninstalled the app from ios or android, we need to send them notifications. Yes, notifications!

Silent notifications which is sent out to users at optimal frequency using CMS (Cloud messaging services). And we track the response code of the pushed notification to differentiate.

For Android, send a push notification to all users at a frequency (say, daily). Send a special parameter in the body to determine that the push notification is only for tracking uninstalls. You shouldn't show anything on the device for such kind of notification, just process it silently.
Suppose, you send a push notification with following payload:

```
{ 
"registration_ids":[ 
"cXA8WRhGWt8:APA91bE3Vgr3x8egGAcriY56Dgdq8CTY-ALukO0UWQwh1k5bUkrG1RbUrjMyFfUrMzah-F3DZaFjHYTogga9D_w3mse6U_Nx7tgWJ_9tdLcumIe0fARAKsiBvxLlBZjBnwujulIYd3zh", "fFN9eAHFqdQ:APA91bGHS6jswwObM1GTpoKzbreMIwnuvz65pzU1ff1d76BQUkvUXuT9k5NSygwoCt-U1cOdalF7VhMiDrndidjrxV25VM8ZglEsoio-mMFYRBHMUGCf61kjCdloFnxygCG7RkXRPA5M" 
    ],
    "data": 
    { 
    "type": "track-uninstall" 
    }
     }
```

The second ID is of a removed app, and the response that we'll receive will be like:

```
{
"multicast_id": 5559150596267635443,
"success": 1,
"failure": 1,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
{
"message_id": "0:1438339632512460 %2930a2c7f9fd7ecd"
},
{
"error": "NotRegistered"
}
]
}
```

You can clearly see it says the device is not registered. And now you can track user from the database and try to get in touch with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google analytics and track app_remove